# Extra folders created when pulling from source control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, starteam

I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2010 and StarTeam to play nice but I'm having a little trouble. I create a web site (not a web application) on my pc and add it to source control. Then when my coworker pulls down a copy to his computer, he ends up with extra folders created in the path. For example, if I add something like this:

```
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\TestWebSiteOne.sln  
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Websites\TestWebSiteOne\Default.aspx  
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Websites\TestWebSiteOne\Default.aspx.cs      
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Websites\TestWebSiteOne\web.config
```

When he pulls it down onto his machine, it ends up like this:

```
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\TestWebSiteOne.sln
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\TestWebSiteOne.vssscc
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\Websites\TestWebSiteOne\Default.aspx
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\Websites\TestWebSiteOne\Default.aspx.cs
   C:\Dev\DotNet\Projects\TestWebSiteOne\Websites\TestWebSiteOne\web.config
```

He's getting an extra copy of "Projects\TestWebSiteOne" or "Websites\TestWebSiteOne" thrown in there.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

**Update:**
It appears this is being caused by the .vsscc file. (This file contains the path "Projects\TestWebSiteOne"). If I delete it from within StarTeam, we can pull down a copy of the project and the folder layout is correct. However, the first time we run the project, the .vsscc file is recreated and added to source control. Now to figure out how to stop this. (Or to just have a blank path in the .vsscc file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `*.vsscc` to your StarTeam exclude list. Right click the folder, Properties... Exclude tab, and add it.